# Can "whenever，wherever, however" be used in noun clauses?

Tags: relative-pronouns, free-relative-clauses

Can "whenever，wherever, however" be used in noun clauses? 
Does the following sentences sound natural to you, native speakers?

e.g.

> I don't know whatever she means. 
>  
>   I don't know wherever the children can be. 
>  
>   I don't know whoever told you that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, they can be. :)

Comment: No, they can't, not like the examples above. @April - no, those sentences do not sound natural to this native speaker.

Comment: @user8543 My comment (answer) is to the title and not the examples. :) That said, ***yes***, whenever, wherever, however can be used in noun clause. *I like whenever she calls me 'cutie'*

Comment: @MaulikV That causes my intuition to twinge slightly... for some reason your clause doesn't seem complete unless it is _I like __it__ whenever she calls me cutie._ But that could just be me. In fact, in that case I wouldn't say that it's actually constituent to a noun phrase, but rather the head of an adverbial phrase. __I'd say that wh-ever words can't actually constitute noun phrases in and of themselves__.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *wh-ever* words are used primarily as heads of free relative clauses. When the *wh-* word is a pronoun (*what*, *who(m)*, *which*) these clauses act most often as NPs, and when the *wh-* word is a proadverb (*when*, *where*, *how*) they occasionally act as NPs.

> [<sub>SUBJECT NP</sub>Whatever she means] is bound to be wrong.
>   [<sub>SUBJECT NP</sub>Wherever the children are] is the place to look for him.
>   [<sub>SUBJECT NP</sub>Whoever told you that] is a very wise woman.
>   [<sub>SUBJECT NP</sub>Whenever you want to go] is fine with me.
>   [<sub>SUBJECT NP</sub>However you did it last time] should work here, too.

So the answer to your basic question is 'Yes'.

However: the particular sentences you give as examples, although syntactically sound, are semantically very unlikely.

*Wh-ever* words always refer to a **set** of possible referents, not a single referent; and they give the hearer a ‘free choice’ to select **any** member of that set as a relevant particular referent. The the *-ever* piece of the word expresses the speaker's indifference to which member of the set is selected.

But in sentences like *I don’t know X* or *I wonder X* or *X is unclear*, a free relative clause standing for X is distinguished by grammarians as an ‘embedded question’ or ‘interrogative content clause’: the clause implies a question—*what?*, *where?*, *who?*. These sentences express a primary concern with identifying the particular referent. Consequently, the *-ever* forms are rarely used here, only the bare *wh-* forms.

> I don't know **what** she means.
>   I don't know **where** the children can be.
>   I don't know **who** told you that.
>   I don't know **when** we're going.
>   I don't know **how** to do that.

Note, however, that the *-ever* forms are often employed as intensifiers (*I have no idea **whatever***), and in conversation you will occasionally encounter this use ‘displaced’ onto the head of a free relative clause. In such cases the *-ev-* syllable will receive strong emphasis:

> I can’t imagine whoEVer she might think she is to carry on like she’s the Queen of England.

But this use is strictly colloquial, and should not be employed in formal contexts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about "however" and "whenever"?Can they be used in noun clauses? Could you give me some examples? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @April See my additions.

Comment: As for "[SUBJECT NPWhoever you did it last time] should work here, too", I am wondering whether you want to say "However you did it last time] should work here, too." Am I right?